# Cannot set property 'value' of undefined inside es6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Upon writing code in es6 following a tutorial, I get error -

```
class APromise {
  constructor(fn) {
    this.state = 'pending';
    this.value = null;
    this.deferred = undefined;
    fn(this.resolve);
  }

  resolve(newValue) {
    this.value = newValue;    // ERROR HERE
    this.state = 'resolved';
    if (this.deferred) {
      this.handle(this.deferred);
    }
  }

  handle(onResolved) {
    if (this.state == 'pending') {
      this.deferred = onResolved;
    } else {
      onResolved(this.value);
    }
  }

  then(onResolved) {
    this.handle(onResolved);
  }
}

const log = v => {
  console.log(v);
};
const myFun = () => {
  return new APromise(resolve => {
    resolve('Hello World');
  });
};

myFun().then(log);
```

Error -

```
this.value = newValue;
           ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

But I'm already inside my es6 class, why is it saying this to be undefined? I tried debugging and looking for same problem in google but I can't find a similar one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `this.resolve` to `fn`, you need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it to the `APromise` instance:

```
fn(this.resolve.bind(this));
```

Demo:

```js
class APromise {
  constructor(fn) {
    this.state = 'pending';
    this.value = null;
    this.deferred = undefined;
    fn(this.resolve.bind(this));
  }

  resolve(newValue) {
    this.value = newValue; // ERROR HERE
    this.state = 'resolved';
    if (this.deferred) {
      this.handle(this.deferred);
    }
  }

  handle(onResolved) {
    if (this.state == 'pending') {
      this.deferred = onResolved;
    } else {
      onResolved(this.value);
    }
  }

  then(onResolved) {
    this.handle(onResolved);
  }
}

const log = v => {
  console.log(v);
};
const myFun = () => {
  return new APromise(resolve => {
    resolve('Hello World');
  });
};

myFun().then(log);
```